# Threaded port scanner python

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, network-programming

```
import socket
import threading
from Queue import *

print_lock = threading.Lock()
serverIp = socket.gethostbyname('www.google.com')

def pscan(port):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        s.connect((serverIp, port))
        with print_lock:
            print('Port %d is open' %(port))
        s.close()
    except:
        pass

def threader():
    while True:
        worker = q.get()
        pscan(worker)
        q.task_done()

q = Queue()

for x in range(30):
    t = threading.Thread(serverIp = threading)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

for worker in range(1, 101):
    q.put(worker)

q.join()
```

I am trying to thread my port scanner in PyCharm however the error I keep receiving is that `serverIp` is an unexpected keyword argument on the line `t = threading.Thread(serverIp = threading)`

What is this blasphemy??

Comment: What is it you're trying to do in that statement? As the error message is correctly telling you, the `Thread` object's constructor does not take a `serverIp` keyword argument: https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects

Comment: So what would go in those parenthesis? I am creating a thread there and serverIp, I guess you can look at it as my 'target'. So normally it would read 'target=threader' (Not 'threading' I caught that error.)

Answer (score 1):

You tried to make it way too complicated. Here's a clearer version, it works in Pycharm. (credits to JackalDev)

```
import socket
import threading
import concurrent.futures
import colorama
from colorama import Fore

colorama.init()

print_lock = threading.Lock()

ip = input(Fore.BLUE + "Enter the IP to scan: ")

def scan(ip, port):
    scanner = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    scanner.settimeout(1)
    try:
        scanner.connect((ip, port))
        scanner.close()
        with print_lock:
            print(Fore.BLUE + f"[{port}]" + Fore.GREEN + " Opened")
    except:
        pass

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
    for port in range(1000):
        executor.submit(scan, ip, port + 1)
```

Comment: Is it possible to make the same code work with Pool or Process?